# Using S3 Subfolder as Django collectstatic destination

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm in process launching a Django (1.11.x) project on AWS (ElasticBeanstalk, S3, RDS). With boto3 and django-storages App I managed that my static files push to S3, straight into the bucket. However the S3 bucket has some other files and directories unrelated to static. For that reason I would like to create a Folder within the S3 bucket called `static` and push all the static files into this specifically designated directory.

My `settings.py` looks like this:

```
[...]
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = AWS_S3_MyKEY
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = AWS_S3_MySECRET
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-1xxxxxxxxxxx1'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False


# general static / media settings
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_URL = '%smedia/' % STATIC_URL 
MEDIA_ROOT = '/static/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '%sadmin' % STATIC_URL 

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    # ...
]
[...]
```

I have some experience with Django, but this is my first project involving AWS and boto. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I create a `custom_storages.py` in my config directory like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    file_overwrite = False
```

Then in my settings:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.StaticStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

You should be able to do the same for `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS_LOCATION reference: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#usage

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
AWS_LOCATION = 'mylife/myrules/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your settings,

```
AWS_LOCATION = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```